# Receiving all results from a Web API with pagination

Tags: wso2, jruby, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I need to connect to a server using a Web API and receive all entries. The server however only provides 100 data entries at most (pagination) and a hint how to get the next batch. What is the proper way to realise that with WSO2 EI?

Using the regular mediators doesn't seem to work for me here. I tried using the Script mediator and perform requests in Ruby (or to be more precise the JRuby package WSO2 is using) - but I'd be required to use a Ruby Gem for processing the JSON (which doesn't seem to be working for me).

Is it possible for WSO2 EI to use Ruby Gems as well?
Or can anyone think of another solution to my problem (which does not necissarily involve writing a custom mediator with Java)?

---

Example API response (limited to 2 entries at a time)

```
{
  "result": {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Test"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Test 2"
        }
    ],
    "cursor": {
        "limit": "2",
        "after": "2",
        "before": null
    }
  }
}
```

The `cursor.after` is the ID of the last data in this query. Calling the HTTP URL with param after=2 will select the next 2 entries. If there are no new entries `cursor.after` is `null`.

Comment: The possible solutions in WSO2 depend on the response you get. Do you get a reply telling you how many 'pages' there are, or only telling you there is more to be had?

Comment: It doesn't tell me how many pages there are. It just provides an ID (which is the ID of the last element) which can be used as offset in the URL (there it's called "after", so it will look for entries after that ID)

Comment: Just added an example response above.

Comment: I would try a sequence that calls the api and stores the result, and if cursor after is not null, call itself. In the second iteration it would call the api using the cursor value, add the result to the previous result etc until the cursor.after is null.

Another option would be nested clones where you keep creating a new clone everytime the cursor.after is not null. And then use an aggregate mediator to collect all the responses.

Comment: That first one sounds good. That's basically just what I did in the Ruby code – I didn't think about transferring that onto sequences. If you post that as your answer I can approve it. :)

Comment: I've been trying not to use many sequences as I can't seem to group them in folders without the Developer Studio breaking ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try a sequence that calls the api and stores the result, and if cursor after is not null, call itself. In the second iteration it would call the api using the cursor value, add the result to the previous result etc until the cursor.after is null.

Another option would be nested clones where you keep creating a new clone everytime the cursor.after is not null. And then use an aggregate mediator to collect all the responses.